# Referencing functions I haven't defined yet in Node modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules

If I'm defining a module with the following code:

```
module.exports = Person;

function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

How come when I require this file the first line doesn't return a ReferenceError, since I haven't defined `Person` yet?

Comment: Its not even anything special with module.exports, If I replace the first line with `console.log(Person)` it works just fine... definitely can't do that from repl or in a browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire JS file is parsed FIRST before anything is executed.  Thus, the function `Person()` exists from the parse step before the line `module.exports = Person` is actually executed.

So, when you do it your way:

```
// Person already exists and is a function
module.exports = Person;

function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

everything works fine because the definition of `Person()` is picked up in the parse stage before execution.

But, if you did it like this:

```
// Person exists, but has no value yet (will be undefined)
module.exports = Person;

var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

It would not work because the `Person` variable would not yet have been assigned when the `module.exports = Person` line executes.  This is one of the main differences between these two methods of defining a function (the timing of when the function is actually available).